# Order By datetime column SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

I'm using a SQLite database which has a datetime column, I stored values of the datetime column with format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" but when I want to select values from Database and order by the datetime column, it gives me a wrong order.

```
SELECT id_user FROM RDV WHERE id_user= ? ORDER BY datetime(Date) DESC
```

I added datetime(Date) just to check if it works but it didn't work either.

Comment: Show some examples of the actual values in that column.

Comment: Hi, sorry i made an error in my post, actually the dates are stored in format "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"  is that make a difference ? this is some examples 12-03-2018 12:00  ,  1-09-2017 ....

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: Wrong format. It has to be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acually i made in error, tha dates where in format "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm" and i must put them in format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm

Answer (score 0):

What is the column name? 
If it's called Date, just remove the call to `datetime()`:

`order by Date desc` (or the name of the field if different)

Comment: Yes it's named Date, and my original query was like that "order by Date desc" but it didn't work

Comment: Is the type of the Date column `datetime` or `date`? Sorting will not work properly if it is date type. My guess is that since your format is missing the seconds and milliseconds, it isn't able automatically guess that it's a datetime.